# Randomize navigate links and grab 1 in webbrowser c# with class or list and random

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I write a program that navigate to youtube and so I will watch video. Now I want to add 3 other videos from me and that every time I start my program I randomly grab 1 of the 3 links. How do I do that?

This is my code

```
namespace youtubeviewerr
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // code die ervoor zorgt dat het programma opstart bij het opstarten van pc
            RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
            key.SetValue("youtube", Application.ExecutablePath.ToString());
            //de webbrowser die navigate naar youtube
            webBrowser2 = new WebBrowser();
            webBrowser2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(78, 446);
            webBrowser2.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Top;
            this.Controls.Add(webBrowser2);
            webBrowser2.Navigate(@"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xQDZogqP4P8&list=PLGonWGLZdZJmvgpBTJDzlMqadJkr6LJ1H&loop=1");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Again? What was wrong with the comments on the last duplicate of this question you posted? They explained exactly what you needed to do, yet instead of following their advice you chose to delete the post and copy/paste it into a another post to start it all over again.

Answer (score 1):

You could place the strings with the urls of the videos in an array, and then select one with a math Random. For example:

```
Random rand = new Random();
string[] array = New string[]{"video1URL", "video2URL", "video3URL"};
webBrowser2.Navigate(array[rand.Next(3)]);
```

That code could work, for the functionality you are looking for, tho it may need some adjustments, and of course you need to replace the array i provided with your own URLs.

You could also replace this:

```
webBrowser2.Navigate(array[rand.Next(3)]);
```

With this:

```
webBrowser2.Navigate(array[rand.Next(array.Length)]);
```

Comment: Thanks mate ^^ didnt realize at time of posting, its kinda weird to code directly into a comment window without an IDE for me hahah, also fixed length cuz i cant spell apparently

Comment: @Skye  Thanks that was what i needed

Comment: No problem! Glad it helped you ^^